# HTML: Setting "input" tag "value" attribute with println() / getParameter()

Tags: html

I am writing a basic search page. If you enter a keyword, say "cookie", in the **search bar** of index.jsp, the results.jsp page will show the search bar displaying the keyword, "cookie" along with the search results.

I am having problem with dynamically assigning the keyword in the results.jsp. My code goes something like this:

```
<input class="textInput" id="txtKeyword" name="Keyword" type="text" value=<%JAVA_CODE%> >
```

I tried out 2 methods to have my keywords displayed/saved properly, both failed. Here are my attempts:

1) `<% request.getParameter("Keyword"); %>`

Result: Keyword was not displayed on the results.jsp's search bar nor assigned to the value attribute.

2) `<% out.println(request.getParameter("Keyword")); %>`

Result: Only part of the keyword string displayed and assigned to the value attrivute. For example, if Keyword="chocolate cookie" then only "chocolate" is assigned to the value attribute and displayed.

**Questioins:**

1) Why does println() make a difference? getParameter("Keyword") returns a String and the value attribute accepts a String.

2) How is that when assigning out.println(getParameter("Keyword")) only the first part of the keyword is displayed/saved?

Can you help me figure it out? Thank you in advance.

Comment: When you view source of your html does value have quotes around it?  E.g. value="chocolate cookie"

Comment: I did not use a String object. I used value=<% request.getParameter("Keyword"); %>. So I guess not?

Comment: It should probably be value="<%JAVA_CODE%>".  If you are outputting value=chocolate cookie, it will parse the space as the end of the param value and cookie as the name of the next one.

Comment: It worked! Putting quotation marks on my request.getParameter() corrected the result.

I would think this will turn my code into a String and the whole line request.getParameter("Keyword") will be displayed, but only the Keyword's value was displayed instead!

Thanks! (If you put it in the answer section then I will accept it!)

Comment: I love the fix, but is it possible for you to answer the first question as well? ;)

Comment: I don't know Java that well but suspect 1) is just returning a value and doing nothing with it so it is discarded.  2) specifically writes it to the output, e.g. HTML page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should probably be value="<%JAVA_CODE%>" (e.g. put quotes around it).

If you are outputting value=chocolate cookie, it will parse the space as the end of the param value and cookie as the name of the next one.

Comment: Right answer. Also remember that to print an expression to the HTML response, the correct form is `<%= expr =>` (the equals is missing in your code).